# Unpredictable behavior of node.js module variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, node-modules

I'm having hard time figuring out why my module isnt sigleton, as it should be by default, and why its variables suddenly resetting. Any attempts to make a variable a member of the module.exports object got the same result with unpredictable behavior.

This is completely baffling to me and I would be grateful for any help.

---

```
//target module, ./api/models/person/index.js:
"use strict";
module.exports = {};
var own_counter = 0;
module.exports.setup = function () {
    console.log('setup, pre own_counter = ' + own_counter);
    ++own_counter;
    console.log('setup, post own_counter = ' + own_counter);
}
```

---

```
//first use, ./api/hooks/sequelizeConnecionsInit/index.js:
...
initialize: function(done){
    var person_orm = require('../../models/person');
    person_orm.setup();
    person_orm.setup();
    return done();
},
...
```

---

```
//second use, ./node_modules/sails-userhooks-ws/index.js:
...
var person_orm = require('../../api/models/person');
person_orm.setup();
...
//(its wrong to write code to node_modules, but I havent figured out yet how to use it with my code without module code change)
```

---

```
//Output:
...
setup, pre own_counter = 0
setup, post own_counter = 1
setup, pre own_counter = 1
setup, post own_counter = 2
...
setup, pre own_counter = 0   //Why resetted???
setup, post own_counter = 1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason was here:
http://justbuildsomething.com/node-js-best-practices/#2
In the first and second using too I called require inside the functions, so when I moved it to head (global scope?), my problem resolved.